# valid_from/valid_to against active_status in dimension table

Tags: etl, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, snowflake-schema

In order to populate a SCD2 dimension table, a marker to note the lastest active row is always beneficial.

There are two ways I can think of 
1) valid_from/valid_to
2) active_status: active/deleted

It is clear that valid_from/valid_to keeps more information, but would that complicate the ETL process a lot?

what are the prons and crons of these two methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are mainly two way to implement SCD2

1 Keep versioning .
  2 Keep start date and end date for a dimension.

In most of times we use second approach with having a active inactive flag.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the from/to dates if you ever want to load historic data.

The current/active flag is just a query helper.